# How to get highest rated comment for another model through Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

This is a pretty straight forward issue but I don't know why prefetch related isn't working for me. My relevant models:

```
class Topic:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    
class Aritcle:
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Comment:
    num_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    word = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to return a list of Articles, and for each article the highest rated comment on that article (max num_likes).

I have a QuerySet[Article] called search_results. I keep trying:

```
search_results.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('comment_set', queryset=Definition.objects.order_by('-num_likes').first(), to_attr="top_comment")
)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to use the attr and it gives me an attribute error:

```
for article in search_results:
    print(article.top_comment)
```

generates:

```
AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'top_comment'
```

I've tried with arbitrary query sets, doing Comments.objects.filter('pub_date') but nothing seems to work

I should note that if I change 'comment_set' to something else such as 'comments' it gives me an error, so comment_set must be a valid part of Article

Comment: can you add the details of the class Article?

Comment: I excluded most of the details as they're irrelevant. I mentioned in another comment that  `search_results` is usually something like `Article.objects.filter(topic=topic, title_text__search=query)`, so I've added those two fields to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't use model object instead of queryset in `Prefetch` (I mean the line `queryset=Definition.objects.order_by('-num_likes').first()`) and it should be a queryset object.

I think one way to showing top comment based on each article is to use something like:

```
search_results.prefetch_related('comment_set') # prefetch related for optimization purpose
```

and then in your for loop get the top comment like following codes:

```
for article in search_results:
    top_comment = article.comment_set.order_by('-num_likes').first() or "Does not have comments"
    print(top_comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest querying the other way to make your life easier.

```
Comment.objects.order_by('id', '-num_likes').distinct('id').select_related('article')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how I'd integrate that as this is for a specific queryset of Article. My Article QuerySet is returned by: `Article.objects.filter(topic=topic, title_text__search=query)` from another function I'm calling (topic is a foreign key and title_text is a charfield for Article).

Comment: It's similar but you'll need to prefix your filters: `.filter(article__topic=topic, article__title_text__search=query)`